# How to "link & merge formatting" text correctly from Excel to Word?

Tags: excel-2016, word-2016

I'm using Excel and Word 2016. I want to copy the text in an Excel cell and paste it in Word using "Link & merge formatting". The problem is, the copied text uses 1 line in word. If I try to write just before or after the text, it gets separated when I update the info in Excel. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Example:

In word:

The    is in the garden.

In excel I have a cell with the word "tree".

When I link the result is:

The

tree

is in the garden.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an end-user issue, not a programming one. Questions on general usage of Word are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Hint: Change the paste format you're using.